# Getting JPEG Error #42 when trying to add new record

Tags: delphi-2010

I have figured out how to store and retrieve a JPEG file in my database. If the JPEG file is there, I can easily edit it, but if I try to enter a new record, I always get JPEG Error #42.  Here are my code snippets. I use btnLabelGetClick to upload an image to the stream to be posted.

```
procedure TfrmWines.AutoSetDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
var
  JPG: TJPEGImage;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  JPG := TJPEGImage.Create;
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TBlobField(wdatamod.mywines.FieldByName('winelabel')).SaveToStream(ms);
    ms.Position := 0;
    JPG.LoadFromStream(ms);
    Image1.Picture.Assign(JPG);
  finally
    JPG.Free;
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmWines.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ButtonsEnter;
  //btnLabelGet.Click;
  wdatamod.mywines.Insert;
  edWinename.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TfrmWines.btnLabelGetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute(Self.Handle) then
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get JPEG error 42 when it's stored in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697699/why-do-i-get-jpeg-error-42-when-its-stored-in-a-database)  It pays to do some basic web search. This has been asked in one form or another so many times before.

Comment: If your blob field is empty, there is no data to load into `TJPEGImage`. You need to check for that condition before calling `LoadFromStream`.

Comment: I did research this.  Researching this lead to me being able to get the current code.  I think I have solved this by disabling the datasource, then adding the record and I no longer get the JPEG Error #42.

Comment: That is still not quite working, disabling the dataset datasource. I either get an access violation or JPEG error again depends on where I put it in the code.  I'll keep on research and trying code.

Comment: The blob field will be empty, so that's what gives the error. I'm trying to bypass that only on a new record being inserted.  In order words, the image is not being looked up because I will be adding a new record and new image to the new empty blob field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this AND coded the way to add a standing image for all new records if I don't have an image I want to use:

```
if autoset.DataSet.State = dsInsert then
begin
   image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromFile('q:\sourcecode\mycellar\images\blk_wht_glass.jpg');
  Exit;
end;
```

Here is the new code that prevents the JPEG Error #42 on adding a new record

```
procedure TfrmWines.AutoSetDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
var
  JPG:TJPEGImage;
  ms:TMemoryStream;
begin
  if autoset.DataSet.State = dsInsert then
  begin
    image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromFile('q:\sourcecode\mycellar\images\blk_wht_glass.jpg');
    Exit;
  end;
  begin
    JPG:=TJPEGImage.Create;
    ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      TBlobField(wdatamod.mywines.FieldByName('winelabel')).SaveToStream(ms);
      ms.Position := 0;
      JPG.LoadFromStream(ms);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(JPG);
   finally
     JPG.Free;
     ms.Free;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You need to use `image1.Picture.LoadFromFile()` instead. The `Graphic` property is not valid until an image has been loaded. This code also does not account for the possibility of the blob still being empty after the record is inserted. You still need to handle that possibility.

Comment: It is not just that it works, it is the safe and correct way to use `LoadFromFile()`. Let `Picture` determine the image type and populate the `Graphic` accordingly.  Don't assume that `Graphic` is valid, or always the expected class type, unless you are always loading the same image type every time.

Comment: @ Remy.  Thanks for the guidance. I am using the same image, but I prefer to use the safe and correct way.

Answer (score 0):

If your BLOB field is empty, there is no data to load into `TJPEGImage`. You need to check for that condition before calling `LoadFromStream()`.

Also, I suggest using `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` instead of using `TBlobStream.SaveToStream()` to make a copy of the BLOB data in memory.  Let `TJPEGImage` read the data directly from the database, the `DataSet` knows how to read/write BLOB data using streams.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TfrmWines.AutoSetDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
var
  Fld: TField;
  JPG: TJPEGImage;
  strm: TStream;
begin
  Fld := wdatamod.mywines.FieldByName('winelabel');
  if (Fld.DataSet.State = dsInsert) or (TBlobField(Fld).BlobSize = 0) then
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('q:\sourcecode\mycellar\images\blk_wht_glass.jpg');
  end else
  begin
    JPG := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      strm := Fld.DataSet.CreateBlobStream(Fld, bmRead);
      try
        JPG.LoadFromStream(strm);
      finally
        strm.Free;
      end;
      Image1.Picture.Assign(JPG);
    finally
      JPG.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure TfrmWines.AutoSetDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
var
  Fld: TField;
  JPG: TJPEGImage;
  strm: TStream;
begin
  Fld := wdatamod.mywines.FieldByName('winelabel');
  if TBlobField(Fld).BlobSize > 0 then
  begin
    JPG := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      strm := Fld.DataSet.CreateBlobStream(Fld, bmRead);
      try
        JPG.LoadFromStream(strm);
      finally
        strm.Free;
      end;
      Image1.Picture.Assign(JPG);
    finally
      JPG.Free;
    end;
  end else
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('q:\sourcecode\mycellar\images\blk_wht_glass.jpg');
  end;
end;
```